# Setting connection in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, connection

I have a requirement that i need to set the connection into the hibernate, and i dont want to let hibenate create the connection. The reason being, till now, we were putting the username, password, connection related stuff into the `hibernate.cfg.xml`, without encryption, which causes problem when we need to test the application, during testing phase.

The requirement is something, like i dont want to make any sort of changes in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`, instead i can add a property file, in which i can add all the connection related properties, and that to in encrypted form. There would also be a field, that states the database type. Now, depending upon the database type, I need to create the connection and set it to hibernate, so that that connection can be used later during processing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the hibenate's documentation, and i found there is a way to create your own connection and then put the same in hibernate.

I followed the below steps :-

1. Added the following property in the hibernate.cfg.xml.

`<property name="connection.provider_class">com.home.framework.HibernateConnectionProvider</property>`

1. created a class HibernateConnectionProvider which implements [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/connection/class-use/ConnectionProvider.html), and overriden methods from the interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to setup hibernate without any xml file. Juse use properties, something like this:

```
HBR_PROPS.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
HBR_PROPS.put("hibernate.connection.driver.class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
HBR_PROPS.put("hibernate.connection.username", "username");
HBR_PROPS.put("hibernate.connection.password", "somepassword");
```

and so on...
then initialize the configuration with:

```
cfg = new Configuration()
   .addClass(com.example.package.First.class)
   .addClass(com.example.package.First.class);
cfg.setProperties(HBR_PROPS);
sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

Now yout can manage the settings in the properties file by reading them out from your own "encrypted_hbr_properties.xml"(example) file, decrypt them in code and setting up in  HBR_PROPS.

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Here is the link where i found the source: [Hibernate_without_XML](http://www.java-entrepreneur.com/50226711/hibernate_configuration_with_no_xml.php)

Comment: I agree to your suggestion, but i need to create connection of my own. According to your suggestion, i am still relying on hibernate to create connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a session factory that would use your custom data source. You would be able to encrypt connection properties any way you like and let your data source decrypt them.